# Angular 7 Package dependencies in Component library

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-library

I've created a a component library in Angular 7 that will be ported to other application and those applications will be able to use the components.

I'm running into a problem where an angular library is installed in the component library but does not get bundled with the component library for use in another application and I'm ending up with errors like this...

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material' in
 'C:\Source\MappingServices\GIT\repos\SomeFolderStructure\node_mo
dules\@myComp\components\fesm5'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@myComp/components/fesm5/components.js
```

How can I bundle libraries like this so that they ride along with the component library are are ready for use without additional installations?

***UPDATE***
Package.json file

```
{
"name": "@myComp/components",
"version": "0.0.1",
"whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
"agm","material", "ol"
],
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
"@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"ol": "^5.3.1"
},
"peerDependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
"@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"ol": "^5.3.1"
},
"publishConfig": {
"registry": "http://someTFSdirectory"
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the component's `package.json` file?

Comment: @AhmedM.Kamal I updated question with the package.json

Comment: @funn-bobby as expected you need to add `@angular/material` to the component's dependencies so when you install the component as a package using `npm I myComponent` it will install `@angular/material` as well.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're using the Angular CLI to generate your library, so you should have a `package.json` and a `ng-package.json` within the folder of your library.

Inside the `package.json` you have to list all dependencies so NPM can resolve them. You have three options:

`dependencies`: Then NPM automatically installs them when someone else uses your library. Dependencies listed here also need to be whitelisted inside `ng-package.json` (`"whitelistedNonPeerDependencies"`)

`peerDependencies`: Then the user of your library has to install the dependency (adding it to his own package.json)

`bundledDependencies`: Then the dependency will be bundled together with your library when building it. This is NOT recommended!

Looking at your `package-json`, one can see that the `@angular/material`-dependency is missing from the `dependencies`-section. That's why you get the error when importing it: NPM does not know it has to install it, so it doesn't, so at runtime there is no `@angular/material`.